# Insert node to a specific position in text among various other nodes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a parent `div` node containing several `span` elements together forming a sentence or paragraph. For example,

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">I </span>
  <span class="normal">love </span>
  <span class="red">you</span>
  <span class="normal">.</span>
</div>
```

I want to insert a `span` node with value of "don't" after "I " in the first child node in the `div` using JavaScript, like this

```
// Note that the position is between the text, not the node positions
// No JavaScript function exists like the below, btw
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].insertNodeAtPos(2, mySpanElement);
```

For this, I have a numerical position (here, 2) such that the first node would be:

```html
<span class="red">I <span>don't</span>
```

And if I had position 3, then the 1st child node would be untouched and the second child node would be:

```html
<span class="normal"><span>don't</span>love </span>
```

So how can I insert a node at any position, regardless of the child nodes in the `div`? The inserted node can be inside the child node too. I need to do this in vanilla JavaScript without any framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just after the `I`

Comment: @Bibberty no, it's after any position offset in the text values of those <span> elements. I had taken 2 just as an example for the position, which would lead to span getting inserted after the "I".

Comment: Ok, but the offset is against the word I notice. Think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

```
var insertedNode = parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
```

- `insertedNode` The node being inserted, that is `newNode`
- `parentNode` The parent of the newly inserted node.
- `newNode` The node to be inserted.
- `referenceNode` The node before which `newNode` is inserted.

Comment: I do not have access to the reference node, since there is no way I can know in which node the position is located. If I have a position 5, how can I know in which <span> node that text offset is located? Of course, from the above example, I can say that 5 text offset is located at the 2nd child node in the <div>. But my application adds child nodes with text dynamically, thus I can't keep track of it.

Comment: Right, I missed the part when you note that you need to insert it in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this uses zero based index. Try changing the value.

```js
// Assumes every word has a span wrapper.
function insertAtNodePosition(pos, element) {
  // get container node
  let container = document.querySelector('div');
  // array of the words (span)
  let words = container.querySelectorAll('span');
  // determine which one to add before
  let word = words[pos];
  
  if(word) {
    container.insertBefore(element, word);
  } else {
    container.childNodes.appendChild(word);
  }
}

let myElement = document.createElement('span');
myElement.innerText = "don't ";

insertAtNodePosition(0, myElement);
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">I </span>
  <span class="normal">love </span>
  <span class="red">you</span>
  <span class="normal">.</span>
</div>
<!--
I want to insert a span node with value of "don't" after "I " in the first child node in the div using JavaScript, like this

// Note that the position is between the text, not the node positions
// No JavaScript function exists like the below, btw
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].insertNodeAtPos(2, mySpanElement);
-->
```